# How to display Data from Json Mapper in Angular 5?

Tags: json, typescript, angular5

I'm beginner in Angular5 with TypeScript and I try to found how to display my data from my JSON..
In fact, I have an API which I create with Java.
In my Angular, I have create a JSON Mapper like this :

My Json from my java look like this :

```
 [
        {
            "type": "SERVICE",
            "nom": "aide-services",
            "equipes": [
                {
                    "nom": "IKKI"
                }
            ],
            "serveurs": [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "nom": "vtcint2",
                    "ip": "10.10.25.45",
                    "indicateurs": {
                        "BUILDDATE": "2018-01-03T06:02:05Z",
                        "STATUS": "OK",
                        "VERSION": "2.2.0-SNAPSHOT"
                    }
                }
            ]
```

Currently, I can display only type and nom from Applications like this :
`{{app.type}} {{app.nom}`
But when I want to display for example data from serveurs I cannot 
`{{app.serveurs}}`
I have in my HTML display `[Object object]`
Please, how can I solve this ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
<code>

interface Applications {
  type : string;
  nom : string;
  equipes: Equipe[];
  serveurs: Serveur[];
}

interface Equipe {
  nom : string;
}

interface Serveur {
  id: number;
  nom: string;
  ip: string;
  indicateurs: Indicateurs;
}

interface Indicateurs {
  BUILDDATE: Date;
  STATUS: string;
  VERSION: string;
}

</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.
I just need to iterate like this :

```
<div *ngFor="let s of apps">{{s.serveurs.VERSION
```

It's just an example to illustrate the solution for people who possibly met the same problem like me.